# How to catch the data type of the argument on kotlin?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have a generic "getResult" function with args as the parameter and then how could the program know is the args have Int type, String type or not both data type?

````
// Coming Soon
fun main() {
    val stringResult = getResult("Kotlin")
    val intResult = getResult(100)

    // TODO 2
    println()
}

// TODO 1
fun <T> getResult(args: T): Int {
    return 0
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
// Coming Soon
fun main() {
    val stringResult = getResult("Kotlin")
    val intResult = getResult(100)
    val bolResult = getResult(true)
    // TODO 2
    println("$stringResult and $intResult now $bolResult")
}

// TODO 1
fun <T> getResult(args: T): Int {
    when(args){
        is String -> {
            return args.length
        }
        is Int ->{
            return args*5
        }
    }
    return 0
}```

That I think my Answer but I should check again with different cases
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the specific type, you can use reflection

```
 val foo = ...
  println("${foo::class.simpleName}")    // returns the generic type
```

But reflection is pretty expensive. Not sure what your use case is, but if you have an idea of the types that are going to be passed into that function, you could return the generic type as the result

```
fun <T> getResult(args: T): T {

}
```

and then check to see if it's one of those instances. i.e. a String or an int

```
val result = getResult(1)
when(result) {
    is String -> { do a thing }
    is Int -> { do a thing }
 }
```

Comment: I want to use this code for this case : if the type is String it will have the String length return value if it has Int type it will return the args * 5 value or if not both it will return 0

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: are you passing in a custom type? There won't be a case where you pass in both a String and an Int unless they're contained within some other class.